# How to fix problem with kernel work in jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel

When i starting work with my jupyter notebook, kernel failed with this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXWXw.png)

all text error

> BlockquoteTraceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
>       result = await result
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
>       type=mtype))
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
>       kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
>       self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
>       yielded = next(result)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
>       super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
>       km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
>       self.write_connection_file()
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
>       kernel_name=self.kernel_name
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
>       with secure_write(fname) as f:
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in **enter**
>       return next(self.gen)
>     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write
>       with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
>   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\Zviad\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-2d4299dc-40de-4b99-a7ce-4e3243899961.json'

Comment: From the last line of the error, this seems like a permission issue.

Comment: Yeah, but why at my laptop I have this kind of problem? Somebody know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem with permission. Should run Jupyter notebook as admin.